# How to filter a list based on 2 properties?

Tags: c#, linq, list

I have a list in my code that I need to filter through and return specific rows based on two criteria.  The List in question is a list of models from a database.  There are two ID properties on each model, one is the ID from the data table and is unique, the other is an ID we use to identify groups and can repeat.  We'll call them ID and GroupID.  Basically, I want the resulting list to have only one of each GroupID, and it should be the one with the highest (numerically speaking) ID.  For example:

**Input:**

```
List<MyModel> modelList = new List<MyModel>
modelList[0].ID = 1   modelList[0].GroupID = 5
modelList[1].ID = 2   modelList[1].GroupID = 5
modelList[2].ID = 3   modelList[2].GroupID = 6
modelList[3].ID = 4   modelList[3].GroupID = 6
```

**Desired Output:**

```
Models at indexes 1 and 3.
```

Comment: Your question and your desired output don't align. Are you wanting the models with **indexes** of `1` and `3` or **ID** of `1` and `3`?

Comment: Indexes 1 and 3, which would be ID 2 and 4

Comment: He wants the highest `ID` from each group. So yeah his desired output is valid @Cameron

Comment: Is it? I don't see it could you show us please? @Cameron

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your solution:

```
var myData = models.GroupBy(model => model.GroupId)
                   .Select(group => group.OrderByDescending(model => model.Id).First());
```

Or you could also do this:

```
var myData = models.GroupBy(model => model.GroupId)
                   .Select(group => group.First(model => model.Id == group.Max(model1 => model1.Id)));
```

For fun, [here's](https://dotnetfiddle.net/C90mBJ) a fiddle.

Comment: This appears to be what I'm looking for, I will test on my end.

Answer (score 2):

Using LINQ:

```
var items = (from model in modelList
             group model by model.GroupID into modelGroup
             select modelGroup.Max(i => i.ID)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

What you have to do here is first order the modelList by ID and then GroupBy the list items by GroupID, then pull the item with max Id value.

```
var result = modelList.OrderByDescending(x => x.ID).GroupBy(x => x.GroupID).Select(x => x.First());
```

the above query will give you the result.

Comment: Hi, this is a hint or a tip but not an answer. Could you please provide a complete answer instead?

Comment: edited with the query. can you please remove the down vote.

Answer (score 0):

```
var newModelList = modelList.GroupBy(ml => ml.GroupID)
.Select(g => new MyModel
{
    ID = g.OrderByDescending(x => x.ID).First().ID,
        GroupID = g.Key
}).ToList();
```

Details

1) `GroupBy` then `Select` to get distinct items over `GroupID`.

2)  `First()` after `OrderByDescending` to get highest `ID`.

3)  `new MyModel`  in `Select` is just to be explicit about the projection.

Comment: Although this code may be help to solve the problem, providing additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it answers the question would significantly improve its long-term value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.

Comment: @oɔɯǝɹ Thanks for your suggestion. Edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [GroupBy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb534304(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
var q = modelList.GroupBy(x => x.GroupID, x => x, 
                             (key, g) => new { 
                                             GroupID = key, 
                                             Id = g.Max(c => c.ID)
                                           });
```

This should group all your elements by `GroupId` and select `Max ID` in one of that groups.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
List<MyModel> modelList = new List<MyModel>();
modelList.Add(new MyModel());
modelList.Add(new MyModel());
modelList.Add(new MyModel());
modelList.Add(new MyModel());

modelList[0].ID = 1; modelList[0].GroupID = 5;
modelList[1].ID = 2; modelList[1].GroupID = 5;
modelList[2].ID = 3; modelList[2].GroupID = 6;
modelList[3].ID = 4; modelList[3].GroupID = 6;

var list = from ml in modelList group ml by ml.ID into r select new { ID = r.Key, MaxGroupID = r.Max() };
```

Comment: Try a create Console Application any copy & paste into the Main method.

Comment: Cool I did not that we can use sql statements in c#. Thanks

Comment: If you need SQL statements, sorry, but this is not the right place. You mark your question with C#! :-)

Comment: It is not my question :D I was just looking

Comment: so what is this if it is not SQL? It just took my attention cz I would need that more often

Answer (score 0):

this might help you
`modelList.GroupBy(model => model.GroupId, g => g.Id).Select(item => item.Max())`